# Terminology for a thermodynamic process in which no work is done

Tags: thermodynamics, terminology

Is there an accepted term to be used when the work done in a process is zero? Fermi, in his book on thermodynamics seems to use "isochoric" even when the work is different from pressure-volume work, but I don't believe that is standard usage. Is there any other word for a process where only heat is transfered?